# ReactJS + Redux - Getting 404 not found on Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, redux, react-router

I am using react with react-router.
When i run the app locally everything is working fine.
When i deploy the app on heroku, if the user tried entering to go to route that does'nt exists, he will get "404 not found nginx".

let say my app page is xxx.herokuapp.com

If someone route to xxx.herokuapp.com/123 => 404 not found.

I tried checking the server and it not getting any request.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using webpack to run your app locally? Heroku needs a way to provide you files. A simple express app which can serve your index.html should be fine

Comment: I am using locally. my index.html working on routes that defined in react-router, only the paths whom not on it not working.

Comment: Defined routes work on heroku or not?

Comment: Nope, where should i define it?

Comment: If you are using create-react-app, follow their instructions at https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#heroku Otherwise, I suggest you to create an express app to serve your static files.

Comment: I did it already... i don't think it's the problem.

Comment: Did you solve this, @MusicGindos? I have the same problem. It works with graphiql but doesn't work with web pages.